# Initializing static variables in static function result in unresolved

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

```
class PossibilisticShellClustering
{
public:
    PossibilisticShellClustering(void);
    ~PossibilisticShellClustering(void);
    static void SetParameters(double deltaDistance);
    static  double deltaDistance
};
```

and i wanto to initialize static variable deltaDistance in function SetParameters. So in *.cpp file I wrote

```
void PossibilisticShellClustering::SetParameters(double deltaDistance)
{
    PossibilisticShellClustering::deltaDistance = deltaDistance;    
}
```

however I get linker erros

> unresolved external symbol "public:
>   static double
>   PossibilisticShellClustering::deltaDistance"
>   (?deltaDistance@PossibilisticShellClustering@@2NA)

Could somebody tell me why ?

```
PossibilisticShellClustering.obj
```

Comment: You have no semi-colon after `static double deltaDistance`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to defined `PossibilisticShellClustering::deltaDistance` in a source file somewhere in your program, usually a .cc or .cpp file.

```
double PossibilisticShellClustering::deltaDistance;
```

What you have in the class body (or would have if it was terminated with a `;`) is only a declaration. Static data members also need a definition.

Comment: And explicitly initialise it, I would say.

Comment: @unapersson: It will be zero-initialized first and as he's writing a function for later explicit assignment, unless he has a special value that it needs to have during start up and explicit initializer seems a bit redundant.

Comment: I hate coming across statics that aren't initialised and then wondering if the guy that created them really wanted them to be default initialised to zero, or just forgot to initialise them to what they should be. Explicit initialisation only takes a few keystrokes, after all.

Comment: @unapersson: I hate coming across statics. ;-)  Enforcing explicit initialization of statics even if you wanted the zero-initialized default is not something I can bring myself to care about greatly. Anyone who manages to forget to initialize a static to some non-zero value that actually matters needs to test their code more thoroughly IMHO.

Comment: Well, I have to disagree here. A good static analysis tool (or even a compiler) can detect non-explicitly initialised statics and IMHO should do so - after all, where's the loss? I agree that in the great scheme of things it probably is not Error #1, but if it is one more thing that can go wrong, why not diagnose it?